# How to use JSF panelGrid

Tags: java, jsf, authentication, grid, panelgrid

Im trying to create a login form using JSF. And not sure on how to use the panelGrid.

The layout of the code is as follows:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
    <p>UserName <h:inputText ............../></p>
    <p>Password <h:inputSecret ............/></p>

    <h:panelGroup>
        COMMAND BUTTON ENTER
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:panelGrid>
```

What im not sure of is how do i justfy what goes in which column etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `h:panelGrid` every JSF tag lands in a new column. If you want 'UserName' and `<h:inputText>` to be next to each other in separate columns your XHTML should look like this:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="4">
    <h:outputText value="UserName" />
    <h:inputText ............../>
    <h:outputText value="Password" />
    <h:inputSecret ............/>
</h:panelGrid>
```

So in your case if you have 4 columns, then first row will be taken by label-input x2, what comes after that will land in a new row. If on the other hand you want each label-input pair to land in a separate row just set the columns attribute to `columns="2"`.

You can also style each column like so:

```
<h:panelGrid ... columnClasses="one-col,two-col,three-col,four-col" >
```

Comment: Columns go side ways though, thats in rows :/ Sorry im totally confused with it and how it works 

I have a registration form that i need doing which takes in these values:

First Name,
Last Name,
Contact Number,
Email Address, 
Password

How would i justify this in a panelGrid Thanks .

Comment: do you want each label-input pair be in a new line?

Comment: Yes i assume, just as a registration form

Comment: Thers an example of what im trying to achieve http://facestutorials.icefaces.org/tutorial/images/converter-basic-main.png

Comment: So for columns = 2, if i have 10 items under the grid it will show up as 5 rows

Comment: I was trying to find it but im new to this